# color coded cryptography using python

Tags: python

I am implementing a research paper as my project. what i am doing is that i am making a new image and assigning each pixel a RGB value. bascially what i am trying to do is create blocks and assign these blocks some RGB value. when i change the values manually it works fine and make all blocks. but when i try this using list it says list index out of range.

```
img = np.zeros((280,280,3), np.uint8) #new image
pixs=70 #number of pixels
l=[208,121,123,156,189,245,255,111,123,125,125,121,131,212] #list of values of R

i=0    
for k in range(img.shape[0]):
    for g in range(img.shape[1]):
        img[k:k+(pixs-1), g:g+(pixs-1)] = (l[i],32,144)
        i=i+1
```

here i am making the blocks and assigning them RGB values. please guide me where i am wrong as i am using python for the first time

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that if `k` runs until the side of the image, `k+pixs` is indeed outside of the image, when `k` is large.

Comment: when i dont use list, it works fine. but when i try to change any value dynamically, this says list index is out of range

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find out what's the problem. Could you please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: done. check the problem again

Comment: Please check [mcve] again.

Comment: i am trying my best to explain the problem. idk what else is needed to explain! :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you try to achieve with the slice assignment, but the cause of the error you mentioned is clear now: analyze the value of `i`. `i` is initially set to `0`, and is incremented by one in every iteration of the inner loop. The loops iterate through every pixel (as `range(img.shape[0])` will iterate every integer between `0 .. img.shape[0]-1`).  The image contains `280*280 == 784000` pixels, so `i` grows bigger than the length of `l` pretty fast, and that will raise an index out of bounds error on `l[i]`.

After seeing your code, I assume that you wanted to set the color of blocks of `pixs*pixs` size. For that, you will have to change the step of `k` and `g`, like: `range(0, img.shape[0], pixs)` (which yields 0, pixs, 2*pixs...). If you do so it will still not work, as there are 16 (== (280/70)**2) blocks in the image, but there are only 14 values in `l`.